# unexpected result of string concatenation

Tags: perl

I have written following code to read from a file list of filenames on each line and append some data to it.

```
open my $info,'<',"abc.txt";
while(<$info>){

    chomp $_;
    my $filename = "temp/".$_.".xml";

    print"\n";
    print $filename;
    print "\n";

}

close $info;
```

Content of abc.txt

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Now I was expecting my code to give me following output

```
temp/file1.xml
temp/file2.xml
temp/file3.xml
```

but instead I am getting output

```
.xml/file1
.xml/file2
.xml/file3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file has windows line endings `\r\n`. `chomp` removes the `\n` ([Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) but leaves the `\r` ([Carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)). Using [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) with `Useqq` you can examine the variable:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper($filename);
```

This should output something like:

```
$VAR1 = "temp/file1\r.xml";
```

When printed normally, it will output `temp/file`, move the cursor to the start of the line and overwrite `temp` with `.xml`.

To remove the line endings, replace `chomp` with:

```
s/\r\n$//;
```

or as noted by **@Borodin**:

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

which "has the advantage of working for any line terminator, as well as removing trailing whitespace, which is commonly unwanted"

Comment: @RobEarl: `s/\s+\z//` has the advantage of working for any line terminator, as well as removing trailing whitespace, which is commonly unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, your file has windows line endings.

The following self-contained example demonstrates what you're working with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $info, '<', \ "file1\r\nfile2\r\nfile3\r\n";
while(<$info>){
    chomp;
    my $filename = "temp/".$_.".xml";

    use Data::Dump;
    dd $filename;

    print $filename, "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
"temp/file1\r.xml"
.xml/file1
"temp/file2\r.xml"
.xml/file2
"temp/file3\r.xml"
.xml/file3
```

Now there are two ways to fix this

1. Adjust the [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to that of your file.

   ```
   local $/ = "\r\n";

   while(<$info>){
       chomp;
   ```

   [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) automatically works on the value of `$/`.
2. Use a regex instead of [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) to strip the line endings

   Since [perl 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Regular-expressions) there is a escape code [`\R`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc) which stands for a *generic newline*.

   ```
   while(<$info>){
       s/\R//;
   ```

   Alternatively, you could just strip all trailing spacing to be even more sure of covering your bases:

   ```
   while(<$info>){
       s/\s+\z//;
   ```